# How to generate more current than available DC

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, dc, power-electronics, boost

I'm not an electrical engineer.

Is it possible to generate more current than an input could supply (DC system)? And if possible, what would it take to make it dynamic?

For example, a regular USB3.1 port can give 5V at 0.9A. What electronic circuit/ICs would I need to have an output of 5V at 3A? What would I need to make the current output variable depending on certain conditions (ranging from 0.9A to 3A in this example)?

Comment: You clearly need a [Turbo Encabulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLDgQg6bq7o).

Comment: You need a battery, such as a USB power bank. Charge it up with 5V @ 0.9A, then discharge it at 3A. But you cannot draw 3A continuously from a USB port rated at 0.9A.

Answer (score 10):

There is but one absolute rule in life when it comes to power supplies...

"You can not get more energy out of a circuit than you put in."

As such your supply is 5V at 0.9A, that is 4.5 Watt.seconds. You are asking for 5V at 3A, that is 15.s. There is no way to do that continually without adding more power from somewhere else. The physic's police will arrest you if you do.

However, if your load is not continuous, you can output 15W.s for 4.5/15 (0.3) amount of the time.  Actually depending on the efficiency of however you are storing that energy, and how much quiescent current the rest of your circuit uses, less than that, perhaps a fifth or a quarter of the time, or less. Storage options include but are not limited to, large capacitors, chargeable batteries etc.

Whether whatever you are doing has the time windows available to store that amount of energy efficiently is beyond the information given in your question.

Comment: You wrote a good answer. I'm still thinking about whether we should have a close reason "OP didn't think about conservation of energy".

Comment: @MarcusMüller... LMAO... touche ;)

Comment: This is, of course, a base lie. In fact, a power supply that produces more output than input is the basis of virtually all perpetual motion machines. :-)

Comment: @Jerry: So tell the OP to go get a perpetual motion machine.  I've got a few spares up at my unicorn ranch I'd be willing to sell for a reasonable price.  Maybe he can find a good deal on Alibaba.

Comment: @Jerry, I saw in a flyer they were on sale at "Ideal Transformers and Diodes R Us".

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Unfortunately, I have it on good authority that [the  world's only functioning unicorn lair is in North Korea](http://newsfeed.time.com/2012/11/30/unicorns-existence-proven-says-north-korea/), and I can't advise that he violate our trade sanctions just to get a measly perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @jameslarge yup.. sorry, I flipped it. fixed I'm trying to show it more as energy / time based rather than watts .. but I may just be muddying it.

Comment: 15 watts (which is 15 joules per second).

Answer (score 7):

You can increase or decrease current or voltage.  What you can't do is increase the product of current x voltage.  That's because current x voltage is power, and you can't create power (energy per time) from nothing.  Physics can be inconvenient like that.

You have a power supply that puts out 5 V at up to 900 mA.  A circuit could use that to provide 3 A.

However, you can't get more power out than in.  (5 V)(900 mA) = 4.5 W.  That's the total power you have to work with.  Even a ideal perfect converter that provides 3 A can only do so at (4.5 W)/(3 A) = 1.5 V.  Of course any real converter will have real losses, so you'll actually get somewhat less than 1.5 V in reality.

If you want (5 V)(3 A) = 15 W from your 4.5 W source, then you either need to provide the missing 10.5 W from elsewhere, or go apply for your own personal exemption to the laws of physics.

Comment: Or build an infinite improbability drive...